# Spark/Python - Slave in Cluster is not used

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm new to Spark. I have the master(192.168.33.10), and slave(192.168.33.12) cluster setup locally, and I'm wrote to following script to demo that both master and slave are running the get_ip_wrap() on its own machine.

However, when I run with the command ./bin/spark-submit ip.py, I only see the 192.168.33.10 in the output, I was expecting 192.168.33.12 in the output as well.

I have also included the trace for my master and work output file as well.

```
import socket
import fcntl
import struct
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

def get_ip_address(ifname):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    return socket.inet_ntoa(fcntl.ioctl(
        s.fileno(),
        0x8915,  # SIOCGIFADDR                                                                         
        struct.pack('256s', ifname[:15])
    )[20:24])

def get_ip_wrap(num):
    return get_ip_address('eth1')

#spark = SparkSession\                                                                                 
#        .builder\                                                                                     
#        .appName("PythonALS")\                                                                        
#        .getOrCreate()                                                                                
#sc = spark.sparkContext                                                                               

conf = SparkConf().setAppName('appName').setMaster('spark://vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:7077')
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

data = [x for x in range(0, 50)]
distData = sc.parallelize(data)

result = distData.map(get_ip_wrap)
print result.collect()
```

vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7$ ./sbin/start-master.sh

starting org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master, logging to /home/vagrant/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-vagrant-org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master-1-vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64.out

vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7$

vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7$ ./sbin/start-slave.sh spark://vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:7077

starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /home/vagrant/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-vagrant-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64.out

vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7$

vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7$

vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7$

vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7$ ./bin/spark-submit ip.py

Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties

17/05/27 17:08:09 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 2.1.1

17/05/27 17:08:09 WARN SparkContext: Support for Java 7 is deprecated as of Spark 2.0.0

17/05/27 17:08:10 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable

17/05/27 17:08:10 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: vagrant

17/05/27 17:08:10 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: vagrant

17/05/27 17:08:10 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to:

17/05/27 17:08:10 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to:

17/05/27 17:08:10 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(vagrant); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(vagrant); groups with modify permissions: Set()

17/05/27 17:08:10 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 59290.

17/05/27 17:08:10 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker

17/05/27 17:08:10 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster

17/05/27 17:08:10 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Using org.apache.spark.storage.DefaultTopologyMapper for getting topology information

17/05/27 17:08:10 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: BlockManagerMasterEndpoint up

17/05/27 17:08:10 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /tmp/blockmgr-ad008702-6e92-4e60-ab27-a582b1ba9fb9

17/05/27 17:08:10 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 413.9 MB

17/05/27 17:08:11 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator

17/05/27 17:08:11 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4040. Attempting port 4041.

17/05/27 17:08:11 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4041. Attempting port 4042.

17/05/27 17:08:11 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4042.

17/05/27 17:08:11 INFO SparkUI: Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://10.0.2.15:4042

17/05/27 17:08:11 INFO SparkContext: Added file file:/home/vagrant/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/ip.py at spark://10.0.2.15:59290/files/ip.py with timestamp 1495904891756

17/05/27 17:08:11 INFO Utils: Copying /home/vagrant/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/ip.py to /tmp/spark-5400808c-1304-404d-ae53-dc6cdb14694f/userFiles-dc94d72e-15d3-4d84-87b9-27e87dcb0f6a/ip.py

17/05/27 17:08:11 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Connecting to master spark://vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:7077...

17/05/27 17:08:11 INFO TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection to vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64/10.0.2.15:7077 after 20 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)

17/05/27 17:08:12 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Connected to Spark cluster with app ID app-20170527170812-0000

17/05/27 17:08:12 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 53124.

17/05/27 17:08:12 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 10.0.2.15:53124

17/05/27 17:08:12 INFO BlockManager: Using org.apache.spark.storage.RandomBlockReplicationPolicy for block replication policy

17/05/27 17:08:12 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 10.0.2.15, 53124, None)

17/05/27 17:08:12 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor added: app-20170527170812-0000/0 on worker-20170527170800-10.0.2.15-54829 (10.0.2.15:54829) with 1 cores

17/05/27 17:08:12 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20170527170812-0000/0 on hostPort 10.0.2.15:54829 with 1 cores, 1024.0 MB RAM

17/05/27 17:08:12 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 10.0.2.15:53124 with 413.9 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, 10.0.2.15, 53124, None)

17/05/27 17:08:12 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 10.0.2.15, 53124, None)

17/05/27 17:08:12 INFO BlockManager: Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(driver, 10.0.2.15, 53124, None)

17/05/27 17:08:12 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20170527170812-0000/0 is now RUNNING

17/05/27 17:08:12 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: SchedulerBackend is ready for scheduling beginning after reached minRegisteredResourcesRatio: 0.0

17/05/27 17:08:13 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: collect at /home/vagrant/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/ip.py:31

17/05/27 17:08:13 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 0 (collect at /home/vagrant/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/ip.py:31) with 2 output partitions

17/05/27 17:08:13 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 0 (collect at /home/vagrant/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/ip.py:31)

17/05/27 17:08:13 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()

17/05/27 17:08:13 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()

17/05/27 17:08:13 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 0 (PythonRDD[1] at collect at /home/vagrant/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/ip.py:31), which has no missing parents

17/05/27 17:08:13 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 4.1 KB, free 413.9 MB)

17/05/27 17:08:13 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 2.8 KB, free 413.9 MB)

17/05/27 17:08:13 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on 10.0.2.15:53124 (size: 2.8 KB, free: 413.9 MB)

17/05/27 17:08:13 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 0 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:996

17/05/27 17:08:13 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 2 missing tasks from ResultStage 0 (PythonRDD[1] at collect at /home/vagrant/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/ip.py:31)

17/05/27 17:08:13 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 0.0 with 2 tasks

17/05/27 17:08:15 INFO CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Registered executor NettyRpcEndpointRef(null) (10.0.2.15:40762) with ID 0

17/05/27 17:08:15 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, 10.0.2.15, executor 0, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 6136 bytes)

17/05/27 17:08:15 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 10.0.2.15:33949 with 413.9 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(0, 10.0.2.15, 33949, None)

17/05/27 17:08:15 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on 10.0.2.15:33949 (size: 2.8 KB, free: 413.9 MB)

17/05/27 17:08:16 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1, 10.0.2.15, executor 0, partition 1, PROCESS_LOCAL, 6136 bytes)

17/05/27 17:08:16 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) in 1050 ms on 10.0.2.15 (executor 0) (1/2)

17/05/27 17:08:16 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 0 (collect at /home/vagrant/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/ip.py:31) finished in 2.504 s

17/05/27 17:08:16 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1) in 119 ms on 10.0.2.15 (executor 0) (2/2)

17/05/27 17:08:16 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 0.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool

17/05/27 17:08:16 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 finished: collect at /home/vagrant/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/ip.py:31, took 2.981746 s

['192.168.33.10', '192.168.33.10', '192.168.33.10', '192.168.33.10', '192.168.33.10', '192.168.33.10', '192.168.33.10', '192.168.33.10', '192.168.33.10', '192.168.33.10', '192.168.33.10', '192.168.33.10', '192.168.33.10', '192.168.33.10', '192.168.33.10', '192.168.33.10', '192.168.33.10', '192.168.33.10', '192.168.33.10', '192.168.33.10', '192.168.33.10', '192.168.33.10', '192.168.33.10', '192.168.33.10', '192.168.33.10', '192.168.33.10', '192.168.33.10', '192.168.33.10', '192.168.33.10', '192.168.33.10', '192.168.33.10', '192.168.33.10', '192.168.33.10', '192.168.33.10', '192.168.33.10', '192.168.33.10', '192.168.33.10', '192.168.33.10', '192.168.33.10', '192.168.33.10', '192.168.33.10', '192.168.33.10', '192.168.33.10', '192.168.33.10', '192.168.33.10', '192.168.33.10', '192.168.33.10', '192.168.33.10', '192.168.33.10', '192.168.33.10']

17/05/27 17:08:16 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook

17/05/27 17:08:16 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://10.0.2.15:4042

17/05/27 17:08:16 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Shutting down all executors

17/05/27 17:08:16 INFO CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Asking each executor to shut down

17/05/27 17:08:16 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!

17/05/27 17:08:16 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared

17/05/27 17:08:16 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped

17/05/27 17:08:16 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped

17/05/27 17:08:16 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!

17/05/27 17:08:16 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext

17/05/27 17:08:16 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called

17/05/27 17:08:16 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-5400808c-1304-404d-ae53-dc6cdb14694f/pyspark-021d6ed2-91d0-481b-b528-108581abe66c

17/05/27 17:08:16 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-5400808c-1304-404d-ae53-dc6cdb14694f

vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7$

vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7$

vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7$

vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7$ cat /home/vagrant/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-vagrant-org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master-1-vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64.out

Spark Command: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -cp /home/vagrant/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/conf/:/home/vagrant/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/* -Xmx1g -XX:MaxPermSize=256m org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master --host vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 --port 7077 --webui-port 8080

========================================

Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties

17/05/27 17:07:44 INFO Master: Started daemon with process name: 9384@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64

17/05/27 17:07:44 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for TERM

17/05/27 17:07:44 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for HUP

17/05/27 17:07:44 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for INT

17/05/27 17:07:44 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable

17/05/27 17:07:45 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: vagrant

17/05/27 17:07:45 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: vagrant

17/05/27 17:07:45 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to:

17/05/27 17:07:45 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to:

17/05/27 17:07:45 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(vagrant); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(vagrant); groups with modify permissions: Set()

17/05/27 17:07:45 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkMaster' on port 7077.

17/05/27 17:07:45 INFO Master: Starting Spark master at spark://vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:7077

17/05/27 17:07:45 INFO Master: Running Spark version 2.1.1

17/05/27 17:07:45 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'MasterUI' on port 8080.

17/05/27 17:07:45 INFO MasterWebUI: Bound MasterWebUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://10.0.2.15:8080

17/05/27 17:07:45 INFO Utils: Successfully started service on port 6066.

17/05/27 17:07:45 INFO StandaloneRestServer: Started REST server for submitting applications on port 6066

17/05/27 17:07:46 INFO Master: I have been elected leader! New state: ALIVE

17/05/27 17:08:00 INFO Master: Registering worker 10.0.2.15:54829 with 1 cores, 2.8 GB RAM

17/05/27 17:08:12 INFO Master: Registering app appName

17/05/27 17:08:12 INFO Master: Registered app appName with ID app-20170527170812-0000

17/05/27 17:08:12 INFO Master: Launching executor app-20170527170812-0000/0 on worker worker-20170527170800-10.0.2.15-54829

17/05/27 17:08:16 INFO Master: Received unregister request from application app-20170527170812-0000

17/05/27 17:08:16 INFO Master: Removing app app-20170527170812-0000

17/05/27 17:08:16 INFO Master: 10.0.2.15:51703 got disassociated, removing it.

17/05/27 17:08:16 INFO Master: 10.0.2.15:59290 got disassociated, removing it.

17/05/27 17:08:16 WARN Master: Got status update for unknown executor app-20170527170812-0000/0

vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7$